# Login form using JSP and DBMS

Tags: java, database, jsp, authentication, javabeans

I'm creating a login form using jsp, java and a database. I have the files

- index.jsp
- loginprocess.jsp


  *and the following java files in a package 'Bean'*
- LoginBean.java
- LoginDao.java
- ConnectionProvider.java
- Provider.java

> index.jsp

```
<form action="loginprocess.jsp" method="post">
    E-mail:<input type="text" name="email" /> <br/ <br/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br/><br/>  
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>" 
</form>
```

> loginprocess.jsp

```
<%@page import="bean.LoginDao"%>  
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.LoginBean"/>  
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>  
<%
    boolean status = LoginDao.validate(obj);
    if (status) {
        out.println("Your'e successfully logged in");
        session.setAttribute("session", "TRUE");
    } else {
        out.print("Sorry, email or password error");
%>  
<jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include>  
<%
    }
%>
```

> LoginBean.java

```
package bean;

public class LoginBean {

    private String email, pass;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
}
```

> LoginDao.java

package bean;

import java.sql.*;

```
public class LoginDao {

    public static boolean validate(LoginBean bean) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from user5 where email=? and pass=?");

            ps.setString(1, bean.getEmail());
            ps.setString(2, bean.getPass());

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            status = rs.next();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return status;

    }
}
```

I'm running this on a Tomcat server and runs except that I always get the same output("Sorry, email or password error") no matter how many times the login is validated.

I have also added a record in the db(I'm using oracle 10g) I don't know properly about the code since I referred online.

The boolean "status" is returned as `false` always from the LoginDao class.

Please guide me how this program works.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution to your problem

In index.jsp change `<input type="password" name="password"/>` to `<input type="password" name="pass"/>`

> Explaination

As this line in `<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>` in your code would call respective setters. Looking at your code I can assure you that is calling `setEmail` ans `setPassword`, as there is no `setPassword` in LoginBean the `pass` becomes null.

> Suggestion

An one more thing that I would want to suggest is that it would be better if you define `scope` in the `<jsp:useBean>`.

Eg:-

`<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.LoginBean" scope="request"/>`

And in scriptlet you call it as

```
<%
LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean) request.getAttribute("obj");
LoginDao.validate(loginBean);
%>
```

It would be much more clearer this way.

Comment: I tried changing the name attribute in the <input > tag to "pass" but it's still the same. I tried the suggestions but with LoginDao.validate(request.getAttribute("obj")); , I get a HTTP response code:500

Comment: @Natrajan Did you keep the scope as request?

Comment: If you have set scope as request and still getting 500. Then do this `LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean) request.getAttribure("obj");` Now send this reference into `validate` method as `LoginDao.validate(loginBean);`

Comment: I am getting this error now:                                                                       { An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /loginprocess2.jsp
LoginBean cannot be resolved to a type
4: <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>  
5:   
6: <% 
7: LoginBean loginbean = (LoginBean)request.getAttribute("obj");
8: boolean status=LoginDao.validate(loginbean); }

Comment: I don't know why it is not working now. I have taken your code and executed on my machine it is working fine. Your code that you have have pasted in your question works simply by changing the field name `password` to `pass` No more changes needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot answer by looking at the code, but here's what you should do,
- First try to figure out if the problem is in UI/Businesslogic or in DB side
- Hard code and return true where you are querying the db. This would tell you if the problem is in DB/queries or in other part of your program
- Do the same and this time hard code and return true from your servlet.